# How can I extend the users collection with Astronomy and accounts-ui?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, astronomy

I need to be able to extend the collection that accounts-ui creates by default of users.

```
import { Class } from 'meteor/jagi:astronomy';
import { Behavior } from 'meteor/jagi:astronomy-softremove-behavior';

/**
 * @class User
 */
const User = Class.create ({
    name: 'User',
    collection: Meteor.Users,
    secured: false,
    fields: {
        emails: {
            type: Email,
            optional: true
        }
    },
    behaviors: {
        softremove: {
            removedFieldName: 'removed',
            hasRemovedAtField: true,
            removedAtFieldName: 'removedAt'
        },
        timestamp: {
            hasCreatedField: true,
            createdFieldName: 'createdAt',
            hasUpdatedField: true,
            updatedFieldName: 'updatedAt'
        }
    }
});

export default User;
```

I wan't use Meteor.user.(), only like to use the User class.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The users collection in Meteor is special. Under the hood in Mongo it is a regular collection.

For security reasons, you can't use the users collection like a regular collection, for example you can update your own user record, but you can't browse and edit other users records.

My advice is to create a separate collection for your user profile information. It's not a perfect solution, but it is better to leave the users collection under the control of the Meteor accounts package.

It is possible to extend the collection to store a few profile type data elements, but even that has some wrinkles, because when a user record is updated, the tracker runs, and your UI will refresh (with possible negative side effects if the refresh isn't expected)